# An expression cannot be used with default constraints. Specify only constants for default constraints in azure synapse sql

Tags: sql, azure, datetime, default, azure-synapse

I want to add a default constraint using CREATE TABLE in AZURE SYNAPSE SQL, but I received the below error message instead. Also tried in alter statement but no luck. I have tried multiple ways but no luck. Could you please help me with the solution.[image]

Comment: As the error message says, you can't use expressions for default constraints in Azure Synapse. You can only use literal values and constants.

Comment: Could you suggest any solution please ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-default-values-for-columns?view=sql-server-ver15) expressions (and functions like `GETDATE()`) cannot be used with defaults:

> Note In Azure Synapse Analytics, only constants can be used for a
> default constraint. An expression cannot be used with a default
> constraint.

The solution is to specify the column as `NOT NULL` and ensure a date is supplied when the data is inserted into the table, eg:

```
INSERT INTO yourTable ( someId, yourDateColumn )
SELECT someId, GETDATE()
FROM someTable;
```

An alternative would be to use `CREATE TABLE AS (CTAS)` and specify the column value there, eg:

```
CREATE TABLE yourTargetTable
WITH (
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN,
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
AS 
SELECT someId, GETDATE() AS loadDate
FROM stagingTable;
```