# Synapse deployment failing through AzureDevops Dacpac deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-synapse, dacpac

I have a table that is modified structurally and has some existing data. Through Devops deployment, dacpac is identifying change but resulting in following error. Strangely the default keyword relates to dynamic masking. If I drop the table manually and redeploy through devops it picks the table not available and creates it without any issues.

```
    ##[error]Error SQL72014: Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 104338, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 An expression cannot be used with a default constraint. Specify only constants for a default constraint.
    ##[error]Error SQL72045: Script execution error. The executed script:
    ##[error]CREATE TABLE [CIM_People].[tmp_ms_xx_employee_leave_request] (
    ##[error] [requested_for_employee_profile_id] VARCHAR (100) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NOT NULL,
    ##[error] [leave_start_dt] DATE MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NOT NULL,
    ##[error] [leave_end_dt] DATE MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NOT NULL,
    ##[error] [successfactors_leave_account_type_cd] VARCHAR (255) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NOT NULL,
    ##[error] [successfactors_leave_request_status_nm] VARCHAR (255) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NOT NULL,
    ##[error] [leave_payroll_calculation_cd] VARCHAR (10) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NOT NULL,
    ##[error] [leave_request_last_modified_dt_utc] DATETIME MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NOT NULL,
    ##[error] [leave_request_external_cd] VARCHAR (255) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NOT NULL,
    ##[error] [requestor_employee_profile_id] VARCHAR
    ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
    ##[error]The Azure SQL DACPAC task failed. SqlPackage.exe exited with code 1
```

Here is actual table script. Any thoughts what is the issue?

```
    CREATE TABLE [CIM_People].[employee_leave_request]
    (
        [requested_for_employee_profile_id] varchar (100) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()')  NOT NULL,
        [leave_start_dt] date MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()')  NOT NULL,
        [leave_end_dt] date MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()')  NOT NULL,
        [successfactors_leave_account_type_cd] varchar (255) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()')  NOT NULL,
        [successfactors_leave_request_status_nm] varchar (255) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()')  NOT NULL,
        [leave_payroll_calculation_cd] varchar (10) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()')  NOT NULL,
        [leave_request_last_modified_dt_utc] datetime MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()')  NOT NULL,
        [leave_request_external_cd] varchar (255) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()')  NOT NULL,
        [requestor_employee_profile_id] varchar (100) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()')  NULL,
        [workflow_request_id] varchar (255) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()')  NULL,
        [leave_day_qty] decimal (18, 2) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()')  NULL,
        [leave_hour_qty] decimal (10, 2) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()')  NULL,
        [leave_comment_desc] varchar (2000) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()')  NULL,
        [leave_request_create_dt_utc] datetime MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()')  NOT NULL,
        [leave_last_modified_by_employee_profile_id] varchar (100) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()')  NULL,
        [source_deleted_ind] varchar (1) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()')  NOT NULL,
        [InsertedLoadId] INT NOT NULL,
        [InsertedLoadDate] DATETIME NOT NULL,
        [UpdatedLoadId] INT NULL,
        [UpdatedLoadDate] DATETIME NULL,
        [Type1SCDHash] VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,    
        [BusinessKeyHash] VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
    )
    WITH
    (
        DISTRIBUTION = HASH([BusinessKeyHash]),
        CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
    )
```

Comment: To narrow down the issue, connect to your SQL server from your local machine and run the scripts above to check whether there is the same error or not. If there is, the issue may be related to your scripts.

Comment: According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-default-values-for-columns?view=sql-server-ver15#Restrictions), in Azure Synapse Analytics, only constants can be used for a default constraint. An expression cannot be used with a default constraint. Check the solution in [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69388865/an-expression-cannot-be-used-with-default-constraints-specify-only-constants-fo).

Comment: I was able to deploy the script directly on DB but not through dacpac deployment task. If the table was dropped and devops ran to create table it worked fine. It is failing only when it has data in it and it for some reason gives the error. Error is misleading as the default keyword is related to masking function and not a default constraint. Also how does it allow to create table in the first place and while table has modifications it fails to alter it in devops deployment.

Comment: Testing using your scripts, I can't reproduce the issue. The deployment is successful. Would you please let me know whether you have inserted data into the table "employee_leave_request" before generating the DACPAC file or after generating the DACPAC file? Do your scripts make any changes to the existing table in DB?

Comment: I had data in the table and renamed only an existing column which resulted in an error. I have not tried adding/dropping column in the same table to see what happens.

Comment: On more test I found out this problem occurs when adding/editing fields of datetime datatype and only happens if the table already existed.